# Modify outgoing messages for a subset of users

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

Is it possible to modify outgoing messages for a subset of users?

I'm just prototyping at the moment, but the eventual plan is that we'll have two (or more) tiers of users all connecting to the same hubs. The hubs are basically just re-broadcasting whatever messages the clients want to send.

The higher tier of users should see all messages. The lower tier of users should not see all messages and should see edited versions of some messages.

I'm trying to work out how best to do this. I thought I'd found the answer by using a [`HubPipelineModule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.hubpipelinemodule(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace WebApplication9
{
    public class MsgFilter : HubPipelineModule
    {
        protected override bool OnBeforeOutgoing(IHubOutgoingInvokerContext context)
        {
            if (context.Invocation.Method == "pong")
            {
                if (((string)context.Invocation.Args[0]).Equals("goodbye"))
                {
                    context.Invocation.Args[0] = "this message has been suppressed for the good of the people";
                }
            }
            return base.OnBeforeOutgoing(context);
        }
    }
}
```

(Eventually, the filtering will need to determine information about the connected user, but I'm not there yet)

Which has been installed during `Startup`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Owin;

namespace WebApplication9
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
            GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new MsgFilter());
        }
    }
}
```

And the hub looks like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace WebApplication9
{
    public class PingHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(dynamic message)
        {
            Clients.All.pong(message);
        }
    }
}
```

(This will eventually move to broadcasts within a specific group rather than going to all clients)

I then have the following code in an MVC Controller's View:

```
@model dynamic

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "title";
}

<h2>title</h2>

<input id="message" type="text" />
<input id="send" name="send" value="Send" type="button" />

<div id="messages"></div>

@section scripts
{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
    var ping = $.connection.pingHub;
    // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
    ping.client.pong = function (message) {
      // Add the message to the page. 
      $('#messages').append('<li>' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
    };
    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
      $('#send').click(function () {
        // Call the Send method on the hub. 
        ping.server.send($('#message').val());
        // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
        $('#message').val('').focus();
      });
    });
  });
  // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
  function htmlEncode(value) {
    var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
    return encodedValue;
  }
</script>
}
```

(Controller method itself is just `Return View();`)

However, when I launch two browsers, enter a message in one and press `Send`, I *expected* my code within `OnBeforeOutgoing` to be invoked twice, once for each connection. This is not the case, it is only invoked once.

**Questions**

So, it would appear that this is the wrong place to implement a filter that will affect *one* connection and not the other.

Is my understanding wrong? Is there a different extension point I should be using?

---

Toolset:

VS 2012, Empty ASP.NET application and then the following packages installed:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.13.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

---

I always complain when people present [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and, on re-reading the above, I realise I may be presenting one myself.

We are thinking of setting up SignalR as a general "event notification" mechanism, both for employees using various internal applications and, eventually, for our suppliers and customers to also access.

Most activity concerns individual customers, so the plan is to have people accessing a particular customer's account to join a Group named after that customer's reference number. And then, when anyone makes changes to that customer, they'll publish events to that group.

However, not all activity that happens to a customer's account should necessarily be visible to the external parties (the customer themselves or our suppliers - whether these need the same access rules or not is not yet decided). Also, not all information *attached* to an event should necessarily be published (e.g. internally, we might need to know that "Joe Blogs", an employee, just did X, but we might want to change that to "Joe (Customer Service)" so as to not reveal an employees personal information)

Comment: Ok, the `OnBeforeOutgoing` seems to be called once because it handles the message as seen from the pipe, the distinction of users is not reachable at this level from what I can see. Imo this separation needs to handled elsewhere. And to add additional groups for e.g. 'admins' and 'customers' doesn't seem very elegant, I agree.

Comment: Upon first connection/registration of a client, his or her role is clear, am I correct? It's not elegant, but having a convention like {customer-name}-{external/internal} to flatten the role within the group name would allow for simple routing of messages on a high level. Interested in seeing more sophisticated ideas to this.

Comment: @rdoubleui - yes, roles should be known when connection occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first question: No, I don't think you can interfere a broadcasted message in a way to modify its content depending on the addressed user (saying that looking at it from the hub perspective).

From the mechanisms provided in a hub I believe the only way is to keep track of connection IDs and then use group calls with a list of excluded connection IDs (external users) to only address specific users. This is stated without knowing how hard it would be to handle connections and reconnections in your particular case.

Every user upon connection would be added to a collection nevertheless if he's within internal users. The internal user would then need to call an additional server method where he needs to be authorized to be taken off the exclusion list (additional authorization triggered from client side).

```
[Authorize]
public void RegisterAsTeamMember()
{
      if (!IDs.Any(u => u == Context.ConnectionId))
      {
           IDs.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
      }
}
```

A broadcast message to all members of a project would result into:

```
Clients.Group("[customer]").broadcastMessage(name, message);
```

and if it is an exclusive message:

```
Clients.Group("[customer]", excludedIds.ToArray()).broadcastMessage(name, message);
```

I know this is not exactly an elegant way. I would even rather then consider the group name convention I suggested in the comments, but I'm happy to discuss or hear from you that you've already considered this.

Comment: I don't think you should accept this. I was hoping for a discussion about it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a membershipprovider and a roleprovider and modify the message according to the subscribers roles using 'RoleProvider.IsUserInRole'.

Comment: Do you have any experience with this approach? Think the problem remains: At what point would you apply the check of `RoleProvider.IsUserInRole`?

Comment: I'm currently using a custom UserProvider but I have no sample of code using a RoleProvider with signalR. I'll try to make it work and I'll come back to you.